# Can I use JON plugin wthout subscription on RHQ?

Tags: rhel, plugin, licenses, jboss

I setup RHQ (not JON) and found [repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/ea/org/jbosson/plugins/fuse/servicemix4-plugin/)

Can I setup and use plugin (example) servicemix4-plugin-7.5.1.redhat-630175.jar on RHQ?
Or only with subscription I can use this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2604821

> You are welcome to use the Maven artifacts from the referenced
>   repository with RHQ. However, please be advised that you may not
>   receive Red Hat support, for the use of any community components.